# How can i make this password match validation work?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this code to check if both passwords match, however it's not working as intended. I've tried what i've seen in some older questions but with no success.

I have this in my component's template:

```
<form [formGroup]="passwordForm">

  <mat-form-field>
    <input #thePassword matInput [type]="hidePasswordButton ? 'password' : 'text'" [formControl]="password"
      (input)="onPasswordInput(thePassword.value)" />

    <mat-label>Enter Password</mat-label>

    <mat-error *ngIf="password.hasError('required')">
      Password is <strong>required</strong>
    </mat-error>

    <mat-error *ngIf="password.hasError('minlength')">
      Must have <strong>at least 8 characters.</strong>
    </mat-error>

    <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="hidePasswordButton = !hidePasswordButton"
      [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'" [attr.aria-pressed]="hidePasswordButton">
      <mat-icon>{{ hidePasswordButton ? "visibility_off" : "visibility" }}</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field *ngIf="!isInputDisabled()">
    <input #ConfirmedPassword matInput [type]="hideConfirmedPasswordButton ? 'password' : 'text'"
      [formControl]="confirmedPassword" (input)="onConfirmedPasswordInput(ConfirmedPassword.value)" />

    <mat-label>Confirm Password</mat-label>

    <mat-error *ngIf="passwordForm.errors?.['mismatch']">
      Passwords <strong>don't match</strong>
    </mat-error>

    <mat-error *ngIf="confirmedPassword.hasError('required')">
      <strong>You must confirm your password</strong>
    </mat-error>

    <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="hideConfirmedPasswordButton = !hideConfirmedPasswordButton"
      [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'" [attr.aria-pressed]="hideConfirmedPasswordButton">
      <mat-icon>{{ hideConfirmedPasswordButton ? "visibility_off" : "visibility" }}</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Then the ts file is something like this:

```
import { matchingPasswords } from 'src/types/password-match-validator';

password = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8), Validators.pattern(/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)/)]);

  confirmedPassword = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]);

  passwordForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    password: this.password,
    confirmedPassword: this.confirmedPassword
  },
    {
      validators: [matchingPasswords]
    });
```

The `matchingPasswords` validator comes from this class:

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, ValidatorFn } from "@angular/forms";

export const matchingPasswords : ValidatorFn = (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const password = control.get('password');
    const confirmedPassword = control.get('confirmedPassword');
    return password 
           && confirmedPassword 
           && password.value !== confirmedPassword.value 
           ? { 'mismatch': true } 
           : null;
           
}
```

This approach kinda works in the sense that if i type something in the password input, say "Abcd1234" and then some random stuff in the confirmation then the mat-error triggers, however, if i type something like "123456aA" in the password input and then something like "123456aB" in the confirmation one the error never shows up even tho both passwords are not exactly the same. At least it doesn't let me submit the form, but i need to show that error message.

I've already tried with the `this.fb.group` approach, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the error for `passwordForm.errors?.['mismatch']` is due to the default behavior of [`ErrorStateMatcher`](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/material/core/error/error-options.ts#L22-L26) which shows the error when these conditions are fulfilled:

1. The control is invalid.
2. Either the control is touched or the form is submitted.

The `confirmedPassword` `FormControl` is required to show an error other than the error from itself, which is the "mismatch" error from the FormGroup.

You need to override the default `ErrorStateMatcher` behavior in order to resolve the issue.

1. Create a custom `ErrorStateMatcher`.

```
export class ConfirmedPasswordErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(
    control: FormControl | null,
    form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null
  ): boolean {
    return !!(
      control &&
      (control.invalid || form?.errors?.['mismatch']) &&
      (control.dirty || control.touched || (form && form.submitted))
    );
  }
}
```

2. Declare the `ConfirmedPasswordErrorStateMatcher` instance in the component.

```
confirmedPasswordErrorStateMatcher = new ConfirmedPasswordErrorStateMatcher();
```

3. Add `[errorStateMatcher]="confirmedPasswordErrorStateMatcher"` to the `confirmedPassword` control.

```
<input
  #ConfirmedPassword
  matInput
  [type]="hideConfirmedPasswordButton ? 'password' : 'text'"
  [formControl]="confirmedPassword"
  (input)="onConfirmedPasswordInput(ConfirmedPassword.value)"
  [errorStateMatcher]="confirmedPasswordErrorStateMatcher"
/>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-n8fiuy?file=src%2Fmain.ts)