# Conflict with 2 validators

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to check if two passwords match. This is what I have tried:

```js
  form = this.fb.group({
    username: ['', [Validators.email, Validators.required]],
    password: ['', [Validators.minLength(8), Validators.required]],
    repeatPassword: ['', [Validators.minLength(8), Validators.required]]
  }, { validators: this.passwordMatchValidator });

  private passwordMatchValidator(formGroup: FormGroup): { mismatch: boolean } | null {
    const password = formGroup.get('password')?.value;
    const repeatPassword = formGroup.get('repeatPassword')?.value;
    if (password !== repeatPassword) {
      return { mismatch: true };
    }
    return null;
  }
```

```html
<mat-error *ngIf="form.hasError('mismatch')">Passwords do not match</mat-error>
```

The problem is, if passwords do not match, the error is getting displayed, but only if the value of `repeatPassword` is less than 8 characters. When it is more, the error disappears. I assume that this is because of `Validators.minLength(8)`. I also removed it and just used `repeatPassword: ['', [Validators.required]]`, but then the error does not show up overall. Why and how to fix this?

Comment: Look like this question is same as what I answered few days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77248238

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have multiple validators on a single form control and one of them fails, the others are not executed. In your case, if the length of `repeatPassword` is less than 8 characters, the `Validators.minLength(8)` fails and stops the execution of the next validation.

I know two solutions that can help you.

1. One is that you can override the default `ErrorStateMatcher`.
2. Another is that you can modify the way you're setting up the validator to ensure both validations are always considered.

In order to modify the way you're setting up the validator, you should

1. Remove `Validators.minLength(8)` from the `repeatPassword` control.
2. Modify the `passwordMatchValidator` to also check the minimum length of the passwords.

Here's the revised version of your code:

```js
form = this.fb.group({
  username: ['', [Validators.email, Validators.required]],
  password: ['', [Validators.minLength(8), Validators.required]],
  repeatPassword: ['', [Validators.required, this.passwordMatchAndLengthValidator]]
});

private passwordMatchAndLengthValidator(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null {
  const password = control.parent?.get('password')?.value;
  const repeatPassword = control.value;
  
  if (repeatPassword.length < 8) {
    return { minlength: true };
  }

  if (password !== repeatPassword) {
    return { mismatch: true };
  }

  return null;
}
```

And in your template:

```markdown
<mat-error *ngIf="form.get('repeatPassword').hasError('minlength')">Password should be at least 8 characters</mat-error>
<mat-error *ngIf="form.hasError('mismatch')">Passwords doesn't match</mat-error>
```

Now it will always validate both the length and whether the passwords match.

Comment: Thank you, the logic makes sense and resolved the problem. However, I have just changed the HTML this way: `<mat-error *ngIf="form.get('repeatPassword')?.hasError('minlength')">Password should be at least 8 characters</mat-error>
<mat-error *ngIf="form.get('repeatPassword')?.hasError('mismatch')">Passwords doesn't match</mat-error>`